# Unhandled "error" event. (/var/task/google/api)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a cryptic error message from Firestore:

> Unhandled "error" event. (/var/task/google/api)

The error appears only when I deploy the code to [lambda](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/concepts/lambdas). Locally, everything works fine.

What does this error mean?

Here is the outline of the lambda code:

```
const firebase = require("firebase/app");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

firebase.initializeApp(...);
admin.initializeApp(...);

function readCollection(collectionName) {
  return admin
    .firestore()
    .collection(collectionName)
    .get()
    .then(...)
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.message); // Unhandled "error" event. (/var/task/google/api)
    });
}

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const todos = await readCollection("todos");
  ...
};
```